# Jetpack Compose snapshotFlow won't trigger for changes within inner States?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
data class WorkSkillStateItem(
    val workSkill: WorkSkill,
    val selected: MutableState<Boolean>
)

var workSkills by mutableStateOf<List<WorkSkillStateItem>>(emptyList())
    private set

... = otherFlow.combine(snapshotFlow { workSkills }) { previouslySelected, current ->
   // won't fire for any changes for "selected: MutabletState"
   // inside "WorkSkillStateItem" - "current[n].item.selected "
   // after calling "updateWorkSkill(...)" function
}.stateIn(...)

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        allWorkSkillsResponse.combine(myWorkSkillsResponse) { all, my ->
            // some logic to map all skills with currenty selected for a user
        }.collect {
            workSkills = it
        }
    }
...

// user changes selection of a skill
fun updateWorkSkill(index: Int, selected: Boolean) {
    workSkills[index].selected.value = selected
}
```

I could use `val workSkillsMap = mutableStateMapOf<WorkSkill, Boolean>()` instead but it only allows to set multiple entries at initialization but at this moment the data is not yet loaded from the repository, it has only set method to add/update one entry

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use mutableStateListOf instead (mutableState only detects when whole item changes, but mutableStateListOf also observe every item in collection):

```
var workSkills by mutableStateListOf<List<WorkSkillStateItem>>(emptyList())
```

And update function like:

```
fun updateWorkSkill(index: Int, selected: Boolean) {
    workSkills[index] = itemList[index].copy(selected = selected) 
}
```

Also there is no need for *selected* field in model to be MutableState, it will be recomposed as item changed:

```
data class WorkSkillStateItem(
    val workSkill: WorkSkill,
    val selected: Boolean
)
```

Comment: the question is about using `val selected: MutableState<Boolean>`, in your case you still need to reassign the WorkSkillStateItem object instead of changing just one field of it (selected).